# Why are Streaming Requests with Libcurl in C++ Slow

Tags: c++, http, iis, streaming, libcurl

I'm using the `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_READDATA` flags to stream requests to my .Net service running on an IIS server. The "read function" is a pretty straightforward callback. Here's a little pseudo code to describe what's going on:

```
size_t a_callback(char* bodyPtr, size_t bytesPerItem, size_t numItems, void* userData) {
  request rqst = *static_cast<request*>(userData);

  const readSize = std::min(bytesPerItem * numItems, rqst.bytesRemaining);
  if (!readSize)
    return 0;

  char* orig = rqst.ptr;
  rqst.ptr += readSize;
  rqst.bytesRemaining -= readSize;

  memcpy(bodyPtr, orig, readSize);
  return readSize;
}
```

The thing is, doing it this way is *way* slower than just using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. For instance:

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, rqst.ptr);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, rqst.bytesRemaining);
```

Does anyone know streaming requests in C++ `libcurl` would be vastly slower than just sending the request data in a big chunk? Is there some option I can tune to try to increase the speed? Am I missing some setting on the server to resolve some kind of bottleneck? I'd appreciate any insights people have.

Comment: Did you profile it? Where is the time spent?

Comment: We are profiling it, but the tools we're using aren't that granular.

Comment: May be it's time to use better tools? :)